# Android Mapbox Marker Labels

Tags: android, label, mapbox, mapbox-marker

I'm trying to figure out how to make a dynamically generated list of markers display a dynamic text label on the map (not in the infoWindow). I know it's possible because I've used this feature in Mapbox Studio - I just can't figure out how to do it on Android! I considered creating a static Bitmap icon with the text incorporated, but that doesn't seem very flexible compared to the Mapbox Studio version, so I'd like to avoid it if I can! Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to do what's called [data-driven styling](https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/maps/overview/data-driven-styling/)

You should use a `SymbolLayer` to show text on a map. If the text you want to show is based on GeoJSON Features in your data set, then use the `get` expression in the `textField` property of a `SymbolLayer`.

```
FeatureCollection featureCollection = FeatureCollection.fromFeatures();
GeoJsonSource geoJsonSource = new GeoJsonSource("source-id", featureCollection);
mapboxMap.addSource(geoJsonSource);

SymbolLayer symbolLayer = new SymbolLayer("layer-id", "source-id")
  .withProperties(PropertyFactory.textField(Expression.get("FEATURE-PROPERTY-KEY")));
mapboxMap.addLayer(symbolLayer);
```

[The Annotation Plugin](https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/plugins/overview/annotation/) simplifies some of this. Also for reference to see how `SymbolLayer`s are used, there is [the Mapbox Android demo app](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo).

Comment: You can also create a separate `SymbolLayer` for the markers. Reference the same GeoJson source as for your text. But for the marker layer, use the `iconImage` PropertyFactory method.

Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
      Actvity.this.getResources(), R.drawable.marker_image);
    mapboxMap.addImage("marker-image", icon);

then later:

SymbolLayer markerLayer = new SymbolLayer("marker-layer-id", "source-id")
      .withProperties(PropertyFactory.iconImage("marker-image"));
    mapboxMap.addLayer(markerLayer);

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I'm after I think! Do I have an alternative if my source is a dynamically compiled list of marker points in Java? I have a database of locations, and want to add them to a list of markers based on a set of information (so static source files aren't an option, unless I can dynamically draw a few points from such a source?). Thanks for the help!

I'm curious about your second suggestion - what's the benefit of doing it this way? Seems a bit more complicated?

Comment: Ahh, nevermind my question! That annotation symbolManager is exactly what I needed. I'll just use SymbolOptions for each marker. :) Thanks so much!

I'm curious about the negative to my question - am I asking something stupid?

Comment: @JakeMadden, not sure what you mean by "I'm curious about the negative to my question"   Anyways, sounds like you're figuring things out. Once a GeoJsonSource is added to the map, any number of layers can reference the unique source id in the layer constructor.

Comment: @JakeMadden , hard to help 'cause idk what your data looks like. If you can get the lat/long from each location in your database, do

List<Feature> featureList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int x = 0; x < listOfLocationsFromDatabase.size; x++) {
          Point singlePoint = Point.fromLngLat(listOfLocationsFromDatabase.get(x).getLongitude(), 
              listOfLocationsFromDatabase.get(x).getLongitude());
          featureList.add(Feature.fromGeometry(singlePoint));
        }
        FeatureCollection featureCollection = FeatureCollection.fromFeatures(featureList);